# Hiding the default value for a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, html.textboxfor

My View Model:

```
public partial class FileTransferFilterCriteriaViewModel
{
    public string Fice { get; set; }
    public string SourceEmail { get; set; }
    public string TargetEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

(Nothing is coming from the DB.)

My Controller:

```
return View(new FileTransferFilterCriteriaViewModel())
```

Here is what gets displayed for both `FromDate` and `ToDate`:

```
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

My HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.Criteria.FromDate)
```

**Questions:**

1. If the date is `null`, how can I suppress the display of the default date value?
2. If the date is *not* `null`, how can I format the date as `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use nullable date in your ViewModel:

```
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: you can also use the [required] attribute in combination with nullable datetime

Answer (score 2):

I have created an editor template and this is working for me.

Changes to view model:

```
[UIHint(UiHintConstants.DateCalendar)]
        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }

        [UIHint(UiHintConstants.DateCalendar)]
        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
```

After that, created an editor template in Views/Shared/EditorTemplate folder called DateCalendar.chtml:

```
@using System.Globalization
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue && !Model.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("1900") && !Model.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("0001") ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker", maxlength = "12", size = "12" })
```

and then utilized it as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x =>x.FromDate)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ToDate)
```

and here is the source code:

```
<input class="datePicker" id="Criteria_FromDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.FromDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

<input class="datePicker" id="Criteria_ToDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.ToDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />
```

Hope this helps some one else.

I couldn't figure out one part though, moving the size and maxlenth out of the template. In this case it is not relevant but may become in some other instances like where i may lock the text box or don't want the jquery calendar. I'll post as soon as i have a handle on this.

Comment: A small modification...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050109/mvc3-editor-template-css-clas-maxlength-and-size

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working perfectly. You are not fetching any data from the database though (as evidenced by passing in a newly instantiated view model `return View(new FileTransferFilterCriteriaViewModel())`). You should consider doing that inside of your controller's action method. To get a shorter date format, use `@Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.Criteria.FromDate.ToShortDateString())`

Comment: That is happening inside the action, just got lazy and only posted the return. I am still getting 1/1/0001.