# Is it possible to make a property nullable and required at the same time in ASP.NET MVC 5 ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following view model

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? LocalFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? LocalTo { get; set; }
}
```

then in the controller I have the following action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "LocalFrom,LocalTo")] FormViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var presenter = new ManagePresenter(model);
        return View(presenter);
    }
    return View(model); // here model.LocalFrom, model.LocalTo should be null
}
```

Here is my HTML form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/Manage/Index" method="post">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="LocalFrom">From</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="LocalFrom" name="LocalFrom" value="@Model.LocalFrom" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="LocalTo">To</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="LocalTo" name="LocalTo" value="@Model.LocalTo)" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I am not sure if making nullable property required is logical or not here. I basically want to populate the input with the name `LocalFrom` in the view with `blank` when `Model.LocalFrom` is null or with the correct value when `Model.LocalFrom` is not null.

**Problem**

Then `ModelState.IsValid` is always returning false even we all the required values are present and valid.

When I make `LocalFrom` and `LocalTo` not nullable I the `ModelState` becomes valid. but in the view will display the time of the beginning of time like so

[image]

How can I pass null value to the view and make the ModelState to validate correctly?

Comment: These might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39094061/2912943 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048838/hiding-the-default-value-for-a-date

Comment: @JeffGuillaume I already have my DateTime property nullable. but the problem is the ModelState.IsValid is always false

Comment: I edited my comment above to add another link, did you check that one too?

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your issue locally or in [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWuRUi).  Seems to work fine in the fiddle, with the exception that you should use `DisplayFormat` as @JeffGuillaume suggests in his first link.

Comment: try to delete `required` at view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow `null` values, then you need to remove the `[Required]` attribute from your `DateTime` properties. A `[Required]` attribute means that the value cannot be `null` so if you submit an empty value (`null`) then `ModelState` will be invalid.

Removing the attributes means that submitting a valid date or `null` will be valid, but submitting an invalid date will still result in `ModelState` being invalid.

In addition, you generating your html manually, and as a result you are not getting correct 2-way model binding (which is why you see the default value for `DateTime` when you return the view). Your view should be

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LocalFrom, new { @class="control-label col-sm-2" }) // assumes you add [Display(Name = "From")] to the property
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocalFrom)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LocalFrom)
    </div>
</div>
```

As a side note, you should remove the unnecessary `[Bind]` attribute. You're using a view model, which means you're already protected from over-posting attacks.

Finally, include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts in your view so that you get client side validation that matches your server side validation attributes and the appropriate error message is displayed in the view.

Comment: I have a question about your note regarding the jQuery libraries. Does microsoft use this jquery validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/? or do they have their own? Additionally, what is the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` for or what does it do for me?

Comment: The scripts required for client side validation are `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. When you apply a validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` (e.g. a `[Required]` attribute), the `HtmlHelper` methods will render a series of `data-val-*` attributes for the input. When the page is rendered, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` reads those attributes and adds rules to `jquery.validate.js` which in turn checks the values of the inputs and displays error messages if not valid.